# Array.map+try/catch passed reference assignment delay

Tags: javascript, arrays, less

i noticed that some how referencing after [].map with try/catch block inside does have a delay. I want to know why and how to avoid such behavior?

my test case was:

-file_picked is a handler of the change event of input with type=file

```
    file_picked: function(e){

        var flist = e.target.files, //all picked files
            parsed = [],        //all ok read
            errors = [];        //all errored

        //parse files
        _.map(flist, function(file){
            var reader = new FileReader();
            //set callbacks
            reader.onload = function(e){    //@reading done
                try{
                    var file_cont = e.target.result,
                        parser = new(less.Parser)({
                            filename: file.name
                        });
                    //run file through the less parser
                    parser.parse(file_cont, function (err, tree) {  //parser done
                        var o = {};
                        if (err) {  //@some parser error occured
                            err('less parser error',err);
                            o[file.name] =  err;
                            errors.push(o);
                        }else{  //@parsed successfully by the less parser
                            o[file.name] =  tree.toCSS();
                            parsed.push(o);
                        }
                    });
                }catch(e){
                    err('reader onload exception',arguments);
                    var o = {}; o[file.name] =  i18n('Parsing failed');
                    errors.push(o);
                }
            };
            reader.onerror = function(e){   //@reading error
                err('reader onerror',arguments);
                var o = {}; o[file.name] =  i18n('Reading failed with error: ')+e.target.error.code;
                errors.push(o);
            };
            //start reading
            reader.readAsText( file );
        });

        //reading completed
            console.log(parsed) 
            for( var i = 0; i < parsed.length; i++ ) {
            console.log(parsed[i],errors);
        }           
    }
```

I see the parsed array in the console!
But it never gets iterated, why?

Thanks in advance

PS.:_.map is underscore.js method, err,lg just console.xxx wrappers.

Comment: Because the operations that you perform in the `map` callback are asynchronous, so the `map` call finishes way before any elements will be appended to the `parsed` array.

Comment: @plalx: I think [].map blocks but to be sure i tested also native for(), $.each, _.each() which are not asynchronous BUT does not work with them either..

Comment: I posted an answer with further explanations.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it in this way so the function that iterates through the parsed files will only run once all the asynchronous calls finished:

_.wrap run a function just after it's been called n times, in your case flist.length

```
[file_picked: function(e){

    var flist = e.target.files, //all picked files
        parsed = [],        //all ok read
        errors = [\],
        readParsed;        //all errored

    //parse files
    _.map(flist, function(file){
        var reader = new FileReader();
      //set callbacks
        reader.onload = function(e){    //@reading done
            try{
                var file_cont = e.target.result,
                    parser = new(less.Parser)({
                        filename: file.name
                    });
                //run file through the less parser
                parser.parse(file_cont, function (err, tree) {  //parser done
                    var o = {};
                    if (err) {  //@some parser error occured
                        err('less parser error',err);
                        [file.name] =  err;
                        errors.push(o);
                    }else{  //@parsed successfully by the less parser
                        [file.name] =  tree.toCSS();
                        parsed.push(o);
                    }

                    readParsed();
              });
            }catch(e){
                err('reader onload exception',arguments);
                var o = {}; [file.name] =  i18n('Parsing failed');
                errors.push(o);
                readParsed();
            }
        };

        reader.onerror = function(e){   //@reading error
            err('reader onerror',arguments);
            var o = {}; o\[file.name\] =  i18n('Reading failed with error: ')+e.target.error.code;
            errors.push(o);

            readParsed();
        };
        //start reading
        reader.readAsText( file );
    });

    readParsed = _.after(flist.length, function(){
        console.log(parsed);

        for( var i = 0; i < parsed.length; i++ ) {
            console.log(parsed[i],errors);
        }
    });
}][1]
```

Answer (score 0):

The `map` function is synchronous, but inside the callback function that you passed to the `map` function, you are performing asynchronous operations.

`reader.readAsText( file );` is asynchronous.

That means the `map` function returns before any data will get appended to the `parsed` array. A simple fix would be to keep track of how many files have been processed by adding counters in the `onload` and `onerror` callbacks. When the number of files that have been processed reaches `flist.length`, you would call a function that would do the work with `parsed`.

Comment: Oh, yes i see now what you mean! This is also true for the parser part...Thanks! Will accept the answer from enr.code, cos will use the _.warp method.

Comment: @LiliputFX, As you whish.